# How should I configure application.properties to connect Azure SQL database in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-sql-database

I created sample spring boot application with mysql db.now  I want to connect Azure SQL database instead of MySQL.how to write application.properties?

Comment: have a look here:  [azure-spring-boot](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot)

Comment: Please refer to this resource:  https://dzone.com/articles/pcf-spring-boot-applications-using-azure-sql-part

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=<JDBC Connection String>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Replace `<JDBC Connect String>`, `<username>`, `<password>`  with your SQL database JDBC connection String, login name and password.

You can copy your Azure database connection String from Azure portal:
  [image]